# Google Analytics - Tracking on exit page

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

i have a from on my page and on submit i will track the submit event. i must on submit goto the other page on a other server. how can i track the submit click before the page change?

Do you have an idea?

Comment: can you post your form code? do you validate the form before sending?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use an "event" to track either the mousedown of the submit button and/or a "enter" keypress

```
// submit button
jQuery('#keyword-submit').bind('mousedown', function (event) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'onsite search', search_keyword]);
});
// textbox
jQuery('#searchKeywords').bind('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) 
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'onsite search', search_keyword]);
});
```